# ggplot2 legend in 2 rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I was unable to find a solution for putting ggplot2 legend in 2 rows.

### Example

```r
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")

ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=state, size=popdensity)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F) + 
  xlim(c(0, 0.1)) + 
  ylim(c(0, 500000)) + 
  labs(y="Population", 
       x="Area", 
       title="") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

**In the above image, I would like to have `popdensity` annotation on top (first row) and `state` annotation in the second row.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `theme(legend.box = "vertical")` and `guide_legend(order = ...)`

```
library(ggplot2)

data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")

ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=state, size=popdensity)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F) + 
  xlim(c(0, 0.1)) + 
  ylim(c(0, 500000)) + 
  labs(y="Population", 
       x="Area", 
       title="") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        legend.box = "vertical") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1), 
         colour = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

[image]